# Angular Filter: Get results unique to a user, sorted chronologically

Tags: angularjs

Let's say I have an array containing the follow objects:

```
{
  user_id: 1,
  message: "Hi there!",
  created: "01-01-2016"
},
{
  user_id: 1,
  message: "Hi there again!",
  created: "01-03-2016"
},
{
  user_id: 2,
  message: "Howdy!",
  created: "01-05-2016"
},
{
  user_id: 2,
  message: "Hi there!",
  created: "01-01-2016"
}
```

I'd like a filter that'll display one object per user_id, but only the most recently created. What could such a filter look like? Would it be a combination of an Angular Unique filter another custom filter to sort by user_id?

Answer (score 0):

I created a snippet that accomplishes what you're looking for, but the most relevant bits are these:

```
<!-- We'll use a custom filter called *mostRecentOnePer* to filter the data.
     It will take three parameters: 
         the data (items) to filter
         the parameter to limit by (user_id)
         the parameter to sort by (created) 
-->
    ...
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | mostRecentOnePer:'user_id':'created'">
```

And the filter itself:

```
.filter('mostRecentOnePer', function() {
    // note the three parameters that correspond to the filter setup in HTML
    return function(items, param, timeField) {

      // sort the items by most recent to least
      items.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (a[timeField] > b[timeField]) return -1;
        if (a[timeField] < b[timeField]) return 1;
        return 0;
      });

      // get the full list of the parameter you want to limit by 
      // in this case, all unique user_id values in your array
      var allParamVals = _.uniq(_.map(items, function(item) {
        return item[param];
      }));

      var filtered = [];

      // for each user_id, find the first item (the most recent) 
      // in the sorted array whose user_id matches that id
      angular.forEach(allParamVals, function(val) {
        var found = _.find(items, function(item) {
          return item[param] === val;
        });
        filtered.push(found);
      });

      return filtered;
    };

  });
```

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    
    $scope.items = [
      {
        user_id: 1,
        message: "Hi there!",
        created: "01-01-2016"
      },
      {
        user_id: 1,
        message: "Hi there again!",
        created: "01-03-2016"
      },
      {
        user_id: 2,
        message: "Howdy!",
        created: "01-05-2016"
      },
      {
        user_id: 2,
        message: "Hi there!",
        created: "01-01-2016"
      }
    ];
    
    
  })
  .filter('mostRecentOnePer', function() {
    return function(items, param, timeField) {
      
      // sort the items by most recent
      items.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (a[timeField] > b[timeField]) return -1;
        if (a[timeField] < b[timeField]) return 1;
        return 0;
      });
    
      // get the full list of the parameter you want to limit by 
      // in this case, all unique user_id values in your array
      var allParamVals = _.uniq(_.map(items, function(item) {
        return item[param];
      }));
      
      var filtered = [];
      
      // for each user_id, find the first item (the most recent) 
      // in the sorted array whose user_id matches that id
      angular.forEach(allParamVals, function(val) {
        var found = _.find(items, function(item) {
          return item[param] === val;
        });
        filtered.push(found);
      });
      
      console.log(filtered);
      return filtered;
    };

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.6.1/lodash.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Message</th>
        <th>Time</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in items | mostRecentOnePer:'user_id':'created'">
        <td>{{ item.user_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.message }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.created }}</td>
      </tr>  
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Hope that helps!